# UITableViewCell's imageView fit to 40x40

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I use the same big images in a tableView and detailView.
Need to make imageView filled in 40x40 when an imags is showed in tableView, but stretched on a half of a screen. I played with several properties but have no positive result:

```
[cell.imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:NO];
[cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```

I am using SDK 3.0 with build in "Cell Objects in Predefined Styles".

Comment: I also have this problem. I also tried imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

Answer (score 32):

I put Ben's code as an extension in my NS-Extensions file so that I can tell any image to make a thumbnail of itself, as in:

```
UIImage *bigImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
UIImage *thumb = [bigImage makeThumbnailOfSize:CGSizeMake(50,50)];
```

Here is .h file:

```
@interface UIImage (PhoenixMaster)
- (UIImage *) makeThumbnailOfSize:(CGSize)size;
@end
```

and then in the NS-Extensions.m file:

```
@implementation UIImage (PhoenixMaster)
- (UIImage *) makeThumbnailOfSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
    // draw scaled image into thumbnail context
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *newThumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();        
    // pop the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    if(newThumbnail == nil) 
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");
    return newThumbnail;
}

@end
```

Comment: With Retina displays, use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` to avoid blurry resizing. :)

Comment: @toblerpwn's note is important so I edited the answer to reflect this. It will now work correctly regardless of screen scale.

Comment: @chaiguy how come I get a no visible interface for '' declares the selector 'drawInRect"'? please help

Comment: @Mediyum Make sure you are declaring the category on the `UIImage` class, which defines `drawInRect`.

Answer (score 12):

I cache a thumbnail version since using large images scaled down on the fly uses too much memory.

Here's my thumbnail code:

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailOfSize:(CGSize)size {
    if( self.previewThumbnail )
        return self.previewThumbnail; // returned cached thumbnail

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    // draw scaled image into thumbnail context
    [self.preview drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];

    UIImage *newThumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    

    // pop the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(newThumbnail == nil) 
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");

    self.previewThumbnail = newThumbnail;

    return self.previewThumbnail;
}
```

Just make sure you properly clear the cached thumbnail if you change your original image (self.preview in my case).

Comment: Where do I put this? Also, is self.previewThumbnail a UIImage? Finally, what is self.preview? An image, a view?

Comment: This is awesome, but wouldn't a custom cell with layout set accordingly be more efficient?

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates?  You can most definitely use this code in a custom cell.  It just creates a thumbnail out of a larger image.

Comment: @zardon This is a method in one of my model classes (which has a "preview" UIImage).  You'll have to edit this a bit to add it to your own model class or at least add a member property called previewThumbnail for it to use for caching.

Answer (score 4):

I have mine wrapped in a UIView and use this code:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self addSubview:imageView];
imageView.frame = self.bounds;
```

(self is the wrapper UIView, with the dimensions I want - I use [AsyncImageView](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/)).

Answer (score 2):

I thought Ben Lachman's suggestion of generating thumbnails in advance rather than on the fly was smart, so I adapted his code so it could handle a whole array and to make it more portable (no hard-coded property names).

```
- (NSArray *)arrayOfThumbnailsOfSize:(CGSize)size fromArray:(NSArray*)original {
    NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[original count]];
    for(UIImage *image in original){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
        UIImage *thumb = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [temp addObject:thumb];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:temp];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you might be able to use this?

```
yourTableViewController.rowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
```

and/or

```
cell.image = yourTableViewController.rowImage;
```

and if your images are already 40x40 then you shouldn't have to worry about setting bounds and stuff... but, i'm also new to this, so, i wouldn't know, haven't played around with Table View row/cell images much

hope this helps.

Comment: No, it is not that i need. I need big images to use.

Comment: He means changing the size, although you are correct in setting the image.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to make this work using interface builder and a tableviewcell.  You can set the "Mode" properties for an image view to "Aspect Fit".  I'm not sure how to do this programatically.

Comment: This is how you would do it programmatically:
yourTableViewCell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: that works, certainly, but using IB is a lot of overhead just to change the size of an image

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `UIImageView.autoresizesSubviews` and/or `UIImageView.contentStretch`.