# How to resize the uitableview cell image?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to resize the same image size in uitableviewcell. I using the same page, not using the another view. I placed everything and ran. But i could not place correctly positioned how to do that. Thanks in Advance. 
Here is the code

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
int count = 0;
if(self.editing && indexPath.row != 0)
    count = 1;

if(indexPath.row == ([imarry count]) && self.editing)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"ADD";
    cell.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    return cell;
}
cell.textLabel.text = [arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.image=[imarry objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)];
return cell;    
 }


 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)UIPicker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)info editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
 {
[UIPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[imarry insertObject:info atIndex:[imarry count]];
[Table reloadData];
NSLog(@"Uploaded image");
}
```

Image picture is

[image]

Comment: Checkout these suggestions: [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055495/uitableviewcells-imageview-fit-to-40x40)
And this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788028/how-do-i-make-uitableviewcells-imageview-a-fixed-size-even-when-the-image-is-sm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

image property is  Deprecated in iOS 3.0.
You can set the imageview of cell but it is readonly property so you can't resize it.

By adding the custom imageview you can solve your purpose.

Comment: if i use custom imageview, when i scrolled fastly it is overlapped. so nly i not use that.

Comment: just comment the line of code which check "if (cell == nil)" in your "cellForRowAtIndexPath".

Comment: so it will create new cell and it will not overlapped.

Comment: thanks and great. It works fine. but  when i scrolled fastly the custom imageview goes down the width size. but height is normal. how to solve this

Comment: for that you have to set the height of cell. Use this method for that. - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6151/discussion-between-unknown-and-reena)